# Imagemagick not found/ installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

This is the staging log of rails project, as the images are not being uploaded.
[image: This is the error I am getting]

Though I have installed ImageMagick
[image: installation screenshot]
and set the environment path to: 
[image]

Still I am getting same error. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on ec2.

Comment: For the sake of searchability, please add code snippets and not screenshots.

Comment: The last screenshot is code @berkes. I knew there is only path issue, thats why I didn't added any code.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Btw, please try and use something a bit newer than ImageMagick v6.7 which is several years old.

Answer (score -1):

add paperclip_command_path: '/usr/bin' to your secrets.yml under environment;